Ubuntu 24.04 : no HDMI sound
I install Ubuntu 24.04
I format the / partition (clean install)
I have no sound on my Philips 4K TV in HDMI.
It was working with previous Ubuntu.
Jabra USB headphone is ok, but not HDMI TV.
I boot on the install USB key : same problem : no HDMI sound.
I try Kernel 6.9.3 : same as 6.8 : no HDMI sound.
# lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller" 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)

# lshw -enable pci -class display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: HD Graphics 530
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       nom logique: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration : depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
       ressources : irq:137 mémoire:ee000000-eeffffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff

# aplay -l
**** Liste des périphériques matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0 : ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 1 : ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 3 : HDMI 0 [PHILIPS FTV]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 7 : HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 8 : HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0


My HDMI Philips TV is in the list.
# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xef140000 irq 138

Thanks

Your issue sound similar to mine.  I figured out that dropping the resolution to one of my monitors caused the problem, so I have to run it at a resolution that is higher than what I want currently.  It not a fix but I think its a pretty important piece of diagnostic info if your situation is the same.  good luck
